# Getting Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing in Java Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, typescript, spring-boot, angular8

Below is my Angular 8 type script code.

```
return this.http.post(fireBaseUrl + endPoint,"{ \n"
+ " \"to\": \"ev6yr0-MLBM:APA91bFfNeY9uWCuaOUtE432oGXFfkg6yqqxPFjbB5pVmmUYQVJzYjDf47eaZ34tJOOuJ1rcJ2A_zgDg5ykTOAAXIcORlc4kWRYmU1vaKM_vXBO-B2MqulSpkzZGWXZGLfc6yaxcICCp\",\n"
+ " \"notification\" : {\n"
+ " \"body\" : "+reqObj+",\n"
+ " \"content_available\" : true,\n"
+ " \"priority\" : \"high\",\n"
+ " \"title\" : "+reqObj.alert+"\n"
+ " },\n"
+ " \"data\" : {\n"
+ " \"body\" : "+reqObj+",\n"
+ " \"content_available\" : true,\n"
+ " \"priority\" : \"high\",\n"
+ " \"title\" : "+reqObj.alert+"\n"
+ " }\n"
+ "}",{headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}});
```

Below is my Spring boot server side code.

```
@PostMapping("/fireBaseMessage")
    public void fireBaseMessage(@RequestBody String payload) {
        System.out.println("payload------->" + payload);
        new RestConsumeController().callRestService(payload);
    }
```

Comment: *Baffled:* Parameter `payload` is declared to be a `String`, so why are you calling `String.valueOf(payload)` to convert the `String` to a `String`?

Comment: That I will handle but the issue is I am not getting anything in payload

Comment: Is it null or empty string? Why don't you receive a Java object instead of String? You should consider creating a Java object that matches the data you want to transfer.